# How to bulkify this code - error handling if more than one record returns

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a code like this:

```
for (Customer__c customerToDelete : Trigger.new) {
    if (customerToDelete.deleted__c) {
        integer count = [select count() from MergeCustomer__c where processed__c = false and 
                         (CAN_Merge_1__c = :customerToDelete.CANText__c
                         or CAN_Merge_2__c = :customerToDelete.CANText__c
                         or CAN_Merge_3__c = :customerToDelete.CANText__c)];
```

If count is not 1, I need to do the error handling. But as the SOQL is in the loop, it can easily exceed the limit. By moving everything into a list will make me unsure how many results returned for each object. Any thoughts?

Updated my code. Sorry I didn't explain well in my first post. In my case, the value can come from any one of the field merge_1, merge_2 or merge_3. And none of them should be duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [General trigger bulkification - best practices](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47469/general-trigger-bulkification-best-practices)

Comment: Just read a great blog post on this topic here https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/08/understanding-bulk-salesforce1-platform.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `GROUP BY` clause in your query so you can move it out of the loop. I don't know what your criteria are because you didn't include them, but do something like this ([more info in the docs](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_count.htm&sa=U&ei=7P5qU-2pFcWNrgfnwIGoCg&ved=0CAcQFjAC&client=internal-uds-cse&usg=AFQjCNE-gGstPYmKm3QjWLzOc2sR6hUO0g)):

```
trigger MergeCustomer on Customer__c (after update) {
    Map<String, Integer> counts = Mew map<String, Integer>();
    for(AggregateResult ar : [select count(Id) c, x from ... group by x]) {
        counts.Put(ar.Get('x'), ar.Get('c'));
    }

    for (Customer__c customerToDelete : Trigger.new) {
        if(counts.Get(customerToDelete.x) != 1) {
            // error
```

Obviously this is not a complete example but it should be enough to get you going!

Comment: Thank you for your response. But just found out my issue is slightly different. My code is: CAN_Merge_1__c in :customersToDelete.CANText__c
                              or CAN_Merge_2__c in :customersToDelete.CANText__c in the where clause. So I am not quite sure which field to group by with. Any thoughts?

Comment: Updated my code in the post to make it clearer. Sorry I didn't explain well in the original post. Any thoughts about this?

Comment: Is there a relationship between the two objects? Could use create a formula field on Customer__c that indicates whether or not it can be deleted?

Comment: No. There is no relationship between customer__c and MergeCustomer__c. In MergeCustomer__c there are four fields which stores customer numbers which are external IDs in customer__c object. But they are not Salesforce IDs. There is a field in customer__c which indicates whether it can be deleted. And this trigger is based on that. But we need to move any objects related to the customer to delete to the merged one. That's why we need a MergeCustomer object